# Traversing through available Views inside ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I dont know but i think im going stupid about If there is any possibilities to retrieve all the available Views in ASP.NET MVC Application.

What i want to do is, User can enter an Search term, then, I have to show the List of available Views that like to that Search Term.

Like :

```
Public ActionResult SearchViews(string qry)
{
    List<string>ViewsCol=new List<string>();

    Foreach(var Vw in Application.Views)
    {
        if(Vw.Contains(qry) 
           ViewsCol.Add(Vw.toString());
    }
    return PartialView("_SearchView",ViewsCol);
}
```

This is the Only sketch i've made, that what i want to do.

So, If this is possible or not? Or there is another way, that i could get the list easily?

**I want to Produce an List of Available Views.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to san physical files in Views folder. You can use code like this:

```
var rootFolder = Server.MapPath("~/");

//recursivly get all the files from 
`rootFolder + "/Views"`
```